# Mingw-w64 File Layout

Tags: layout, mingw

I installed the multilib version of mingw-w64 so I could build both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries. Here's a tree representation of the files: http://pastebin.com/r4QUnbwJ. If you only want to view the directories, see this instead: http://pastebin.com/2m6uqt4E. It looks like there are duplicate files in some cases, like in the bin directory. Are they different in any way? Also, I see one directory named "mingw" and another named "x86_64-w64-mingw32". They look about the same in content. Again, what is the difference?

Basically, I just want an explanation of the file layout. I'm not expecting a description of each file, but it would be good if some of the main concepts within mingw-w64 (multilib) were addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the /mingw directory can safely be deleted. It is only needed for the strange GCC build system (and can even be empty in some cases).

The x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin directory contains executables called by gcc/g++/gfortran/etc. internally. Don't delete them.

There doesn't seem to be a "standard" directory structure, sometimes the x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib(32) and x86_64-w64-mingw32/include directories contain the same files. Sometimes the same files are even in the root include and lib(32) directories. If you need an expert's answer, feel free to post to the [minwgw-64 mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mingw-w64-public), a lot of knowledgeable people reside there.

Comment: Thank you. Right, so the x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin directory contains important executable files. What about the bin directory (just bin)? It seems to contain exactly the same files, except there are more. I thought I'd quickly ask you this in case you knew. I'll be sure to look into the mingw-w64 mailing list.

Comment: @someguy: the root bin directory is the one you add to PATH and those are the executables that you as a user (or through things like make or cmake or ...) use to compile and link code

Comment: What are programs like gcc etc. doing in x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin then? I don't see the need to have two instances of the same program.

Comment: @someguy: what distribution are you using (filename and download location). Those shouldn't be there. The sezero personal builds from mingw-w64.sourceforge.net are very good and I use them all the time.

Comment: @rubenvb [Sorry about the late reply.] The download URL is http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Multilib%20Toolchains%28Targetting%20Win32%20and%20Win64%29/megasoft78/mingw-w64-bin_x86_64-mingw_4.5.2_20110222_multilib_megasoft78.7z/download

Comment: @someguy: yeah, I thought so. These builds are very bloated, don't know why exactly. Sezero builds, although not multilib, are more refined IMHO.